# What is the name of this small black insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Location: South India

Size: 1-2 cm

[image]

Comment: Did you see it recently?  Time of year would be useful.  More useful would be the habitat in where you saw it:  woodland?  Swamp?  Metropolitan?

Comment: Metropolitan, 2017, Night Time, Its on my front door, may be it is new invented species found by me, may be who knows.

Comment: +0. Your photo isn't of such good quality. Try to use the best camera you have available — preferably an SLR camera — and forcing the flash setting to "on". It might help to boost your camera's ISO setting.

Comment: Was there a strong pungent, stinking smell along with the insect (that could be perceived from more than 1 meters distance)? Also mention the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precise identification of insects requires use of microscopic lens and an immobile specimen.
I have neither of those here; also, my reference material is focused on North American species.  Nevertheless, with what I have available to me, it is most likely a member of order Hemiptera, family [Alydidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alydidae):
[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alydus_calcaratus_MHNT_Dos.jpg]

Alydidae are mostly active during the day, so your specimen was probably resting and saw a nearby artificial source of light.  They use their piercing mouth-parts to suck the juices out of herbaceous seeds.  Unless yours was discovered in a heavily urbanized area, I would venture that this one feeds off nearby grasses and trees.